# How to extract vell value by range in excel?

Tags: excel

i have excel sheet who head in every 5th cell and any cell from between is member of head
how can extract member of any head in this format :

```
Head1,member1,member2,member3
Head2,member1,member2
Head3,member1,member2,member3,member4
```

my excel file is :

```
head1
-
-
member1
member2
-
-
head2
member1
-
member2
-
-
-
head3
member1
-
member2
member3
member4
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is the format (example) of the headers and members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT F1
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select NULL as noorder)) AS RowNum, *
      FROM Tables
     ) as alias
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Extract()
    Dim r As Range, textRow As String, out As Range
    Set r = [A1]
    Set out = [B1]
    Do While r.Value <> ""
        If InStr(r.Value, "head") > 0 Then
            If textRow <> "" Then
                out.Value = textRow
                Set out = out.Offset(1)
                textRow = ""
            End If
            textRow = textRow & "," & r.Value
        End If
        If InStr(r.Value, "member") > 0 Then textRow = textRow & "," & r.Value
        Set r = r.Offset(1)
    Loop
    If textRow <> "" Then
        out.Value = textRow
        Set out = out.Offset(1)
    End If
End Sub
```